# Python Program to Find count of repeated adjacent elements in array

Tags: python, list, count

i want to write a python program that has to count the repeated elements in adjacent position in an array. and i want to display the number of occurrence count.

```
# Example 
alist=[1,2,2,3,3,5,6]  # ----- output - 4
alist=[1,2,3,4] # -------------output - 0
alist=[4,5,6,6,8,8,8,8] # -------output - 8
```

i tried

```
alist=[1,20,4,4,4,50];
i =0;
nextele=0;
temp=0;

while(i < len(alist)):
  'print(alist[i])'
   temp = alist[i];
   nextele =alist[i+1];\\here i am getting error out of bound when it iterates last elelment
  i=i+1;
```

Thanks in Advance---

Comment: What have you tried so far ? It would be great to add your sample code so that we can help.

Comment: Actually i am new to the python. i was iterated array. to find adjacent position i am getting out of bound exception. i don't know how to predict

Comment: @KarthickAnbazhagan Edit your question to show your code attempt and the traceback of your error; otherwise "i want to write a python program" looks like "I want someone to write a python program for me."  See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why do you expect `[4,5,6,6,8,8,8,8]` to give output 8? Shouldn't it be 6?

Comment: 6 numbers that have adjacents or 4 pairs of adjacents, but 8 <what>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have `alist[i+1]`  in for loop , you cant go through list until end , so you have to end it one element before end:

```
for i in range(len(alist)-1):
    if(alist[i] == alist[i+1]):
        counter+=2    # since you count both elements

alist=[1,2,2,3,3,5,6] # 4
alist=[4,5,6,6,8,8,8,8] # 8
```

Comment: Contrary to what the OP said, the last example has 8 total elements, but they all aren't repeating, so how is the answer 8??  There are 2 6s and 4 8s adjacent, so wouldn't the answer be 6?

Comment: He count each pair of element as 2, so `(6,6),(8,8),(8,8),(8,8) -> 2+2+2+2 = 8` there are 3 pair of 8s

Comment: Still an odd way to count, 6 digits or 4 pairs, but 8 <what>?

Comment: I don't exactly know what is logic behind that kind of count , but OP counts this way!

Comment: here i am checking both forward and backward elements for each and every element.consider 6. before that 5.avoid it. next one is also same number so increment count to 1.like wise..

Answer (score 1):

Use `for x in range(len(aList)-1)` when iterating through the list to prevent getting an `IndexError`. Compare `aList[x]` and `aList[x+1]`, and increment a counter by two if they are the same.

```
c=0
for x in range(len(aList)-1):
    if aList[x]==aList[x+1]:
        c+=2
```

Answer (score 1):

An efficient way to do this is to use `sum` with a generator expression that zips `alist` with `alist[1:]` so we can compare adjacent items of `alist`.

```
data = [
    [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6],
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [4, 5, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8],
    [1, 20, 4, 4, 4, 50],
]

for alist in data:
    a = sum(2 for u, v in zip(alist, alist[1:]) if u == v)
    print(alist, a)
```

**output**

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6] 4
[1, 2, 3, 4] 0
[4, 5, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8] 8
[1, 20, 4, 4, 4, 50] 4
```

---

If you actually want a total count of repeated items, you can use a list comprehension (or generator expression) with `itertools.groupby` to find the repeated groups, then another generator expression to sum the lengths of groups that contain more than 1 element.

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [
    [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6],
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [4, 5, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8],
    [1, 20, 4, 4, 4, 50],
]

for alist in data:
    runs = [len(list(g)) for _, g in groupby(alist)]
    repeats = sum(u for u in runs if u > 1)
    print(alist, repeats)
```

**output**

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6] 4
[1, 2, 3, 4] 0
[4, 5, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8] 6
[1, 20, 4, 4, 4, 50] 3
```

That list comprehension can be combined with the generator expression:

```
for alist in data:
    repeats = sum(u for u in (len(list(g)) for _, g in groupby(alist)) if u > 1)
    print(alist, repeats)
```

Comment: Thank you for your detail explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_count(num_list):
    count=0
    i=0
   
    while(i<(len(num_list)-1)):
        if(num_list[i]==num_list[i+1]):
            count+=1
        i+=1
    
    return count
num_list=[1,2,2,3,4,4,4,10]
print(get_count(num_list))
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

```
lis=[0,1,1,0,1,2,2,3]                #list declared
count=0                          #count initialised
for i in range(len(lis)-1):
       if lis[i]==lis[i+1]:      #checking the value with the adjacent values
              count+=1
print(count)
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.